# How to create a glowing text box effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, photo-editing, effects

Can someone please tell me how to create that glowing text box [image]

I know how to add glow to text. Actually I'm not even sure it's the glow effect which has been used here. I can't understand ho to end up with this text/box in the image.

Comment: Can anyone please describe the gradient specifications of the purple overlay layer ? I think it's going from a purple to a blue but I'm just not able to achieve this. The wall is somehow appearing more white than this photo. Maybe it's more than 2 colors or something with opacity. Please help.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried? As-is, your question is rather broad and asks quite some work to write an answer for. Please post a screenshot of your attempts and why you aren't content with the results. Thanks.

Comment: I just can't understand what to do. I just made text pink and added that outer glow but the white effect I am not getting. It seems like here white text has been superimposed on pink text but I don't know how to change text thickness (to make it thinner). I am not asking for step by step process I just want to know what has been done here so I can do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tv scan lines" for the lines. The blurring of red and blue looks like a "fake 3D anaglyph effect" - the "Dream" text looks like a simple outer glow, and the Japanese text looks like a "neon sign" effect. Google those terms if you want to find tutorials.

When you ask questions here - best to limit them to one effect at a time, otherwise your question will get put on Hold, for being too broad.

Also it's not such a good idea to add so many effects to one image, otherwise you just end up with effect overload.

Comment: Can you make out the order in which they were applied ?

Comment: The text seems to be under the TV scan lines - so looks like everything is probably arranged using layers, rather that one effect run over another.  It's essentially a composite of effects, probably using layer blending modes.

Comment: The red/blue blurring is likely an attempt at emulating VHS color bleed. Some examples in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyvCbpS0kFk In terms of 'too many effects' I usually agree, though it appears all of these effects in this image are actually trying to emulate one effect = "crappy VHS recording" (A common thing, actually)

Comment: @DA01You could be right, but its also similar to a fake 3d anaglyph effect, an example here  https://blog.123rf.com/create-3d-anaglyph-effect-4-easy-steps/ - I can't remember my VHS tapes being that bad, LOL, but thank goodness we don't need to worry about VHS tapes any more!

Comment: Can you tell me what has been done to achieve that seemingly glowing japanese text box ?

Answer (score 2):

All of the effects in this image are attempts at emulating analog TV recording (VHS). We can argue as to how successful they are. :)

- horizontal lines = [scan lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scan_line). emulating the pixels on a low resolution screen (oddly seen more as an effect rather than a real thing on most TVs)
- shifted pixels (on the text) = emulating poor tracking on a VHS tape where the head isn't perfectly aligned with the data.
- overall glow/color shifting = emulating color bleed on a VHS tape. Common on well-worn tapes and/or tapes recorded at extremely slow speeds.

I found this video advertising various VHS effects that gives a nice overview of the common styles people go after: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyvCbpS0kFk

Comment: Can you tell me what has been done to obtain that seemingly glowing japanese text box ?

Answer (score 1):

The effect is usually refereed to as a "glitch" effect.

[This tutorial is one of MANY examples how to tackle it.](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-your-photo-looks-like-a-frame-from-vhs-tape--cms-26562)

Now to break-down what each effect is:

- The scan-lines (black lines over the whole image) is done with a simple pattern brush or a texture pattern. Google for more information and the method you find easiest.
- The text is a simple pixel font with an outer glow added and the same scan-line added as a pattern overlay. To make the middle part move off center like that, rasterize the text and use the selection tool to select a portion and move it to either side.
- For the red/blue halo effect [this is one of MANY MANY tutorials on how to achieve it](https://www.howtogeek.com/69368/how-to-make-3d-photos-out-of-any-image/).